# How to assign category to all subcategory products?

Tags: product, category

I have to assign all subcategory products to parent category in bulk. I searched a lot but i didn't get any option in backend.

- parent category

  - Sub category -1

    - product-1
    - product-2
  - Sub category -2

    - product-1
    - product-2

Comment: cant you just set anchor to yes in your root category? will that do for you?

Comment: no it is not working

Comment: make sure you didn't set your category to `show cms block` only. Also try reindexing and clearing the cache, the usual stuff. I'm not sure what else could be wrong here

Comment: @Yorrd how to do reindexing? what do mean root category in my case (parent category or above parent (first category)? It is showing in backend only menas ( parent category (200) ).

Comment: system > index (or something along these lines) > select all > refresh index (or something along these lines ;) )

Answer (score 2):

Lets say that the main category id is `$categoryId`.

You need to do this:

Create a file called `update.php` on the same level as `index.php` with this content

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

define('MAGENTO_ROOT', getcwd());
$mageFilename = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;

Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
Mage::app();
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(0));

$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
$allProducts = $category->getProductsPosition();
foreach ($category->getChildrenCategories() as $child) {
   $childProducts = $child->getProductsPosition();
   $allProducts = array_merge($allProducts, $childProducts);
}
$category->setPostedProducts($allProducts)->save();
```

Then just call the file in your browser. `http://magentoroot.com/update.php`.
Make sure you backup your database first, in case I'm wrong.

And make sure to remove the script from your webserver again afterwards.

Comment: can i do with backend? how can i run this script?

Comment: You can also do it manually from the backend. I thought you need an automated solution.  See my updated answer anyway.

Comment: thanks  marius. but i dont want automated solution because i am beginner in magento. Can u tell me how to do manually from backend for `all subcategory products`?

Comment: There is no quick solution to do it from the backend. You have to open 2 tabs. In one edit the main category, in the other one edit each subcategory. Search for each product in each subcategory and assign it to the main category.  But I if you need this only for display on frontend you don't need to assign all products manually. You can just set the field `is anchor` to `yes` for the main categories and it will display on frontend the products from all subcategories.

Answer (score 2):

Here the perfect code for assign products in a specific category.

main category id is `$categoryId`

```
<?php

define('MAGENTO_ROOT', getcwd());

include_once "app/Mage.php";

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

Mage::init();
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
umask(0);
Mage::app('admin');

set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');

$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
$allProducts = $category->getProductsPosition();

foreach ($category->getChildrenCategories() as $child)
{
       $childProducts = $child->getProductsPosition();
       foreach($childProducts as $productId=>$position)
       {
            if(!array_key_exists($productId,$allProducts))
            {
                $allProducts[$productId] = $position; 
            }
       }
}
$category->setPostedProducts($allProducts)->save();

?>
```